# Power BI dataset, ADF and Cosmos DB

Tags: powerbi, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I was wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to move data using Azure data factory with a Power BI dataset as source to the Azure Cosmos DB?

Comment: Power BI is not supported as the dataset in Data Factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power BI is not supported as the dataset in Data Factory. Please ref the supported [connector overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview).

It means that we can't read the data from Power BI as source to Cosmos DB directly.

HTH.

Comment: This is helpful as it answers my question, so thank you for that. 
May I ask a follow up question as this is not supported. Do you know if there are any clever workaround methods that would make it able for me to get this as a source?

Comment: Hi @palmy, as I know about Data Factory, there isn't a good workaround. I don't know where you pull the data in Power BI. Mostly, I would suggest you use Excel instead.